# How to set gnome-terminal's character set encoding according to the system one calls?

Tags: character-encoding, gnome-terminal

The employees of our company use gnome-terminal run from Debian workstations to access a variety of systems running different O/Ss on our local network.  Everything works very well except that the host systems and their applications use different character sets, either ISO-8859-1 ("Latin 1") or UTF-8, and the server applications notably do NOT adapt to the locale of the user.  This requires the user to manually set gnome-terminal's character set encoding each time one starts a new session!

(In case that's not clear, we always want to log into system X using ISO-8859-1, and always log into system Y using UTF-8.  This has to do with the relative antiquity of the O/S of each system, the older ones having little or no accomodation of UTF-8 while the newer ones deal rather grumpily with ISO-8859-1.)

It seems to me that gnome-terminal's character set encoding should be associated with the system one's logging into instead of the system one's calling from.  And that therefore, the character set should be one of the parameters that can be pre-set in the profile.  This is the way other terminal emulators behave, notably the Windows and Mac emulators that we use outside the office.

But in lieu of configuring it in the profile (which is not possible), does anyone know a way of setting the character set encoding as part of a command line invocation of gnome-terminal?

I've been trying to solve this annoyance off-and-on for years... any solution would receive our eternal gratitude. :)

Answer (score 1):

in the good old times, gnome-terminal support --disable-factory, you can set up for local editing files:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GDM_LANG="de_DE@euro"
export LANG="de_DE@euro"
export RC_LANG="de_DE@euro"
export LC_ALL="de_DE@euro"
gnome-terminal --disable-factory
```

or remote access to a linux-box:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GDM_LANG="de_DE@euro"
export LANG="de_DE@euro"
export RC_LANG="de_DE@euro"
export LC_ALL="de_DE@euro"
gnome-terminal --disable-factory --tab --title="Server1 DE" --command "ssh user@Server1"
```

Now at gnome 3.10 I get

```
... Option "--disable-factory" is no longer supported ...
```

So, I am with you and will keep looking ...

Mario

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

LANG=en_US.iso885915 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal